# Trying to understand and learn OPENCAFE (by Rackspace)

Tags: python-2.7

Please assist me how to learn and understand the fundamentals and the way to become proficient in OPENCAFE framework. The documentation is very high level. Please suggest any good tutorial too.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you be specific and share what you've tried so far. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for taking time to read the question. I have learnt Python basics, setup a virtual Ubuntu environment on my machine. I have gone through the official Opencafe documentation (but it is quite high level). I need some working examples/implementations to refer so that I can visualize the overall framework. Thanks.